# When working in WPF, should I be using controls from System.Windows.Controls or System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: wpf, winforms, forms, xaml, controls

So I am starting to use XAML to create WPF applications in Visual Studio, and it seems a LOT of the controls are different. Same name, but different.

Most notably (for me) is the Treeview and RichTextBox.

Since I am working in WPF, should I use `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` or `System.Windows.Controls.TreeView` (same for rich text boxes, etc.)?

I do not like the way that the controls in `System.Windows.Controls` work. It may be because I am used to them in Forms, but for example, I don't get why `Controls.RichTextBox` does not have a Text or a Clear method.

At the same time, it is really annoying having to use <wf:TreeView /> notation a lot, so I try to use the `Sys.Windows.Controls` versions of stuff as much as I can.

Is one way better than the other? Or is it just preference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred way is of course using WPF-native `System.Windows.Controls`. I think you'll get used to them. WPF controls are superior to Windows Forms ones due to their support of binding, animation, styling, etc.

The WPF controls are feature-rich, but the features are sometimes implemented not the same way as the Windows Forms counterparts. In particular, for `RichTextBox` you can use [`RichTextBox.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) for working with the text inside.

For example, getting the text from a `RichTextBox` can be done as follows:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                                    richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
string text = textRange.Text;
```

Comment: oh. ok, that doesnt look to bad (that is exactly what I needed to do with RTB's haha). I will keep in mind that the functionality is probably there, I just might have to dig for it! thanks :)